# Captured image in Android App is not getting saved in the phone

Tags: android, photoeditorsdk

Hi Stack Overflow team,

Below is the java code of PhotoEditor Android app for capturing image or choosing the photo from Gallery and then editing and saving the image in the phone.

Following is the MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.example.photoeditor;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.AdobeImageIntent;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  public static final String IMAGE_URI = "IMAGE_URI_KEY";

  private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
  private static final int IMAGE_EDITOR_RESULT = 1;

  private ImageView mEditedImageView;

  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mEditedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.edited_image_view);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
      Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(getIntent().getExtras().getString(IMAGE_URI));
      Intent imageEditorIntent = new AdobeImageIntent.Builder(this).setData(imageUri).build();
      startActivityForResult(imageEditorIntent, IMAGE_EDITOR_RESULT);
      finish(); // Comment this out to receive edited image
    }
  }

  // Do something with the edited image
  @Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      switch (requestCode) {
        case IMAGE_EDITOR_RESULT:
          Uri editedImageUri = data.getParcelableExtra(AdobeImageIntent.EXTRA_OUTPUT_URI);
          Log.d(TAG, "editedImageUri: " + editedImageUri.toString());
          Bundle extra = data.getExtras();
          if (extra != null) {
            boolean changed = extra.getBoolean(AdobeImageIntent.EXTRA_OUT_BITMAP_CHANGED);
            Log.d(TAG, "Image edited: " + changed);
            if (changed) {
              mEditedImageView.setImageURI(editedImageUri);
            }
          }
          break;

        default:
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected request code");
      }
    }
  }

  public static Intent getIntent(Context context, Bundle bundle) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    if (bundle != null) {
      intent.putExtras(bundle);
    }
    return intent;
  }
}
```

Following is the HomeActivity.java file:

```
package com.example.photoeditor;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Objects;

import static android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA;
import static android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
import static android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
import static android.content.pm.PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private static final String TAG = "HomeActivity";
  private static final int GALLERY_RESULT = 1;
  private static final int CAMERA_RESULT = 2;
  private static final String FILE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY = "com.example.photoeditor";
  private static final int CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE = 1001;
  private static final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE = 1002;
  private String mCapturedImagePath;

  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
  }

  public void openCamera(View view) {
    // check for camera permission if not granted before
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, CAMERA) != PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      String[] cameraPermission = { CAMERA };
      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, cameraPermission, CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);
    } else {
      dispatchImageCaptureIntent();
    }
  }

  public void openGallery(View view) {
    // check for storage permission if not granted before
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      String[] storagePermissions = { READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE };
      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, storagePermissions, STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);
    } else {
      dispatchGalleryIntent();
    }
  }

  private void dispatchGalleryIntent() {
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_RESULT);
  }

  private void dispatchImageCaptureIntent() {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
      File photoFile = null;
      try {
        photoFile = createImageFile();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      if (photoFile != null) {
        Uri photoFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, FILE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY, photoFile);
        Log.d(TAG, "dispatchImageCaptureIntent:photoFileUri: " + photoFile.toString());
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_RESULT);
      }
    }
  }

  @Override public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
      @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
      case CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE:
        if (grantResults[0] == PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
          dispatchImageCaptureIntent();
        } else {
          Toast.makeText(this, "Required camera permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        break;

      case STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE:
        if (grantResults[0] == PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
          dispatchGalleryIntent();
        } else {
          Toast.makeText(this, "Required storage permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
              .show();
        }
        break;

      default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected request code");
    }
  }

  private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
    mCapturedImagePath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
  }

  private Bundle uriToBundle(Uri imageUri) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(MainActivity.IMAGE_URI, imageUri.toString());
    return bundle;
  }

  @Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      if (requestCode == GALLERY_RESULT) {
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        startActivity(MainActivity.getIntent(this, uriToBundle(Objects.requireNonNull(imageUri))));
      } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_RESULT) {
        File imageFile = new File(mCapturedImagePath);
        Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
        startActivity(MainActivity.getIntent(this, uriToBundle(imageUri)));
      }
    } else {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Image not loaded.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }

  public static Intent getIntent(Context context) {
    return new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
  }
}
```

Problem what I am facing is, after capturing and editing the photo from the app, when I save the image, the photo does not get saved anywhere in the phone but it says 'Saving...'.
But after saving, app automatically exits
Saving photo is working fine when editing photo from Gallery in the phone. Saving issue is only for camera captured photo through this app.

Can anyone please help with the solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this to save Image

```
/**
     * Save Bitmap file
     *
     * @param finalBitmap bitmap to store
     * @param folderName  dst folder
     * @param fileName    dst filename
     * @return Absolute path of file.
     */

    public static String saveFileInSDCard(Context context, Bitmap finalBitmap, String folderName, String fileName, Bitmap.CompressFormat compressFormat) {

            if (context == null) {
                return null;
            }
            File file = new File(makeDirectory(folderName) + File.separator + fileName + ".png");
            if (file.exists()) {
                Log.i("fileUtils", "Exists?? " + file.exists()
                        + " && " + file.delete());
                Log.i("fileUtils", "Exists?? " + file.exists());
            }

            //to compress bitmap before save
            //Bitmap finalBitmap = BitmapUtils.compressSampleBitmap(bitmap,1024);

            try {

                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

                finalBitmap.compress(compressFormat, 100, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                Log.i(TAG, "Saved: " + file.getAbsolutePath());

                /* Update gallery app */
                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{file.getAbsolutePath()},
                        null,
                        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Scanned " + path);
                            }
                        });

                return file.getAbsolutePath();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }


public static String makeDirectory(String folderName) {

        File myDir = new File(root + "/" + folderName);
        if (!myDir.exists()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Making Folder ->" + myDir.getName());
            //will create only single dir
            //myDir.mkdir();

            //will create all required directory specified in the path
            myDir.mkdirs();
        }
        return myDir.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

Comment: "return file.getAbsolutePath();" is giving error as "Incompatible types: Required: java.io.File;  Found: java.lang.String"

Comment: @user2201935 you have to use Async task for saving Image.

Comment: Oh, I don't know about that , is it possible to tell me how to exactly place that code in my existing code ? Or such help is against stack overflow ?

Comment: In dispatchImageCaptureIntent function, if I use current code 'photoFile = saveFileInSDCard();' in place of existing code 'photoFile = createImageFile();' ,  i get the error 'saveFileInSDCard() in HomeActivity cannot be applied to Parameters and Arguments Context context, Bitmap finalBitmap, String folderName, String fileName, Bitmap.CompressFormat compressFormat'

Comment: waiting for your answer